# Javascript: Function in a freshly opened window is not found

Tags: javascript, html

I am coming from Java and try to learn Javascript right now. Doing that I have a problem to understand some behaviour I wrote.

I like to have two windows. caller.html opens called.html and invokes a function called printMe().

This is my code for caller.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> PDSA #4.1 : Page 1 - Communication between Windows </title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        fenster = open("called.html");
        fenster.printMe();
    </script>
</body>
```

and this is called.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> PDSA #4.1 : Page 2 - Communication between Windows </title>
    <script>
        function printMe() {
            ausgabe = document.getElementById("toChange");
            ausgabe.innerHTML += "Changed!";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="toChange"></div>
</body>
```

Nothing happens when called.html is opened and from The Javascript Console in Chrome I can see the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'printMe'
(anonymous function)
```

Newbish as I am I don't get it - why is printMe not found? The function is there and I see it in the code. Can you point me to the error?

Thanks in advance for any hints
André

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use jquery, do it inside of, this would make your life easier..

```
// on the second page
$(document).ready(function() {
  printMe();
});
```

or maybe this would work:

```
// on the first page
fenster = open("called.html");
$(fenster.document).ready(function(){
   fenster.printMe();
});
```

if it's not working, you can call setTimeout before calling the function to make sure the child window done loading

```
// on the first page
fenster = open("called.html");
setTimeout(function(){
   fenster.printMe();
},2000);  // 2 seconds before invoking (increase if not enough)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I still don't get what the problem with my code is. From a syntax point of view it should be fine, shouldn't it?

Comment: Aargh, can I delete my feedback? I pressed the wrong button! No offense. I am sorry...

Comment: Thank you - the timeout did the trick. So the child window was not loaded when the parent window called it. I marked your response as the answer. But I think I accidently voted it down before - is there any chance to delete the down-vote? I am new to stack overflow!